# Is the Amazon being cleared at the rate of X football fields a minute?

Tags: environment

I've heard it mentioned in the media in different forms, the Amazon is being cleared at a phenomenal rate.

Is there any factual evidence to support this claim?

Here is [an article from Greenpeace](http://www.greenpeace.org/international/en/news/features/amazon-destruction/)'s website from 2005 which claims the rate is 6 football fields a minute.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This article](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/news/amazon-rainforest-clearing-rate-falls/story-e6frg6u6-1111114183982) cites the Brazilian environment ministry figure of 14,000 square kilometres of forest felled from Aug 05 to July 06. If a football field is 50x100m (0.005 square kilometres), that's roughly 2.8 million football fields at rate of ~5.32 per minute. I'd say their claim is a fair one, based on the round number provided by the ministry, my lack of a specific date range and the variability in size of football pitches.

That said, Brazil has made significant reductions in their clearing activities in recent years, and 6 football fields per minute is likely not the current rate. [This 2010 Mongabay article](http://news.mongabay.com/2010/1006-fao_forest_cover.html) claims that declines in annual worldwide totals for land clearing are primarily due to the reductions made by Brazil. (Emphasis below is mine)

> FAO figures show deforestation across 121 tropical countries averaged 9.34 million hectares per year between 2000 and 2010, down from 11.33 million hectares per year in the 1990s. **The decline has accelerated since 2005 due Brazil's dramatic reduction of deforestation in the Brazilian Amazon**, which peaked at 27,772 square kilometers in 2004 but is expected to come in at less than 8,000 for 2010. 
>   [image]

Comment: This answer conflates "forest felled" with "deforestation" which are two different concepts.  The result of "felled forest" _could_ be "deforestation".  However, "felled forest" could also lead to regeneration as part of sustainable tree farming practices.  For example, [this report on BC](http://www.for.gov.bc.ca/hfp/sof/2010/SOF_2010_Web.pdf) provides a figure of 12,000 Ha per year of "deforestation" annually (p117) and a figure of 90 million m3 (225,000 Ha assuming 400 m3/Ha) annually (p136).  In other words, only about 5% by area of "forest felled" resulted in "deforestation".